# Are hid4java set-up and tear-down operations expensive?

Tags: java, hid, hidapi

I have started prototyping a solution using [Gary Rowe](https://stackexchange.com/users/170199/gary-rowe)'s [hid4java](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java/) library with good success.  The [example](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java/blob/develop/src/test/java/org/hid4java/UsbHidDeviceExample.java) provided in that project's test package is a good start, but I have a more general question regarding the proper usage pattern for this library.

Specifically, I'm wondering if the following set-up operations are expensive, and should be done *once*, or are designed to be performed as part of *each interaction* (command/response) with an HID device?

```
 // Get HID services
 HidServices hidServices = HidManager.getHidServices();
 hidServices.addHidServicesListener(this);
```

The same applies to the tear-down operation:

```
 hidServices.shutdown();
```